# onAppear in List swiftUI not getting called consistenly in iOS 16 and works perfectly in iOS 15

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, ios16, onappear

In lists, in iOS 16 onAppear is strangely not getting called for row which are visible later. Im downloading the image in on Appear and then setting it.In iOS 15, on appear is called consistently.

```
List {
  ForEach(0..<(viewModel.rows.count), id: \.self) { index in
    if let imageModel = viewModel.getImageModel(index: index) {
      SomeCustomView(imageModel)
        .onAppear {
          if imageModel.image == nil {
            imageModell.loadAdBanner()
          }
        }
    }
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
          HStack(spacing: 0) {
            HeaderView(viewModel:
                                      TitleViewModel(headerTitle: viewModel.rows[index].headerTitle))
            Spacer()
            TitleView(viewModel: TitleViewModel(row: viewModel.rows[index]))
          }
          .frame(height: 36)
          .padding(.horizontal, 16)
          .shimmering(active: viewModel.showShimmer)
          .background(viewModel.showShimmer ? .colorDCDCDC : Color.clear)
          CategoriesList(l1Category: viewModel.categories[index],
                         categories: viewModel.categories[index].subcategories,
                         showShimmer: viewModel.showShimmer)
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 16)
      }
      .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Make the row take up full width
      .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()) // Remove row insets
      .padding(0)
  } else {
 sameCode without listSepeartor(.hidden) 
}
```

Comment: This is a guess, but I think Lists in iOS 16 are based on CollectionViews and not TableViews so the behaviour was different. Note that "onAppear" has always meant "added to the view hierarchy" in SwiftUI, and not "appears on screen." I would instead suggest using coordinateSpaces of the list and the row and check the geometry of something to determine when it appears on screen.

Comment: Yes Lists are based on CollectionViews in iOS16, what do you mean by using coordinate spaces?

Comment: You'll need to remove the for loop and view model those are not SwiftUI compatible concepts. You need an array of `Identifiable` items as either a let, state/binding or computed var (if sorting/searching) then you can use the ForEach View.

Comment: @megha there's a good article here on the topic: https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/